# Is there a package that allows to write correctly times in hours, minutes and seconds in mathematical mode?

Tags: macros, siunitx, date

This question is followed by this one: [Is it possible to adapt a duration calculation macro to use it in a foreach loop?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/516958/138900)

---

I'm looking for a package, or even a macro that allows me to simply write duration calculations for young students.
Like for example this (Lebossé-Hemery 1957 classe de sixième):

[image: Lebossé-Hémery 1957 classe de sixième]

I prefer this notation updated with `min` for minute (and not `m`).

I found this code: http://forum.mathematex.net/latex-f6/module-sinuitx-et-le-temps-t11198.html#p108990

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifmtarg}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{number-unit-separator=~}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\sitime}[1]{\sitime@aux#1;;;\@nil}
\def\sitime@aux#1;#2;#3;#4\@nil{%
  \@ifmtarg{#1#2#3}%
  {%
    \PackageError{siunitx (modified)}%
                 {Empty \string\sitime\space argument}{}%
  }%
  {%
    \@ifmtarg{#1}{}{\SI{#1}{\hour}\@ifmtarg{#2#3}{}{\csname l_siunitx_number_unit_separator_tl\endcsname}}%
    \@ifmtarg{#2}{}{\SI{#2}{\minute}\@ifmtarg{#3}{}{\csname l_siunitx_number_unit_separator_tl\endcsname}}%
    \@ifmtarg{#3}{}{\SI{#3}{\second}}%
  }%
}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\sep}{\qquad}
\begin{document}

$\sitime{10;7;12}-\sitime{9;13;8}$

\end{document}
```

It gives this, the spacing between hours and minutes are poorly managed, but the macro is convenient:

[image: screenshot]

1. Is there a package that allows this to be done natively?
2. Any ideas to improve this macro?
3. Another macro?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can have a friendly syntax:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\hms}{ >{\SplitArgument{2}{;}}m }
 {
  \ensuremath{\andrec_hms:nnn #1}
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \andrec_hms:nnn
 {
  \group_begin:
  \bool_set_false:N \l__andrec_hms_thinspace_bool
  \__andrec_hms_print:nn { 0#1 } { h }
  \tl_if_novalue:nTF { #2 }
   {
    \__andrec_hms_print:nn { 0 } { m }
   }
   {
    \__andrec_hms_print:nn { 0#2 } { m }
   }
  \tl_if_novalue:nTF { #3 }
   {
    \__andrec_hms_print:nn { 0 } { s }
   }
   {
    \__andrec_hms_print:nn { 0#3 } { s }
   }
  \group_end:
}
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__andrec_hms_print:nn
 {
  \int_compare:nT { #1 != 0 }
   {
    \bool_if:NT \l__andrec_hms_thinspace_bool { \, }
    \int_eval:n { #1 } \, \mathrm{#2}
    \bool_set_true:N \l__andrec_hms_thinspace_bool
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\hms{7;40;21}+\hms{3;17;5}+\hms{2;4;20}$

$\hms{12;41;}+\hms{0;47;20}+\hms{7;0;37}$

$\hms{5;12;45}-\hms{4;9}$

\end{document}
```

For a missing value you can use 0 or nothing; a trailing missing value can be omitted altogether; so for 2 hours you can say `\hms{2}`, for 2 hours and 2 minutes `\hms{2;2}`.

[image]

With a separator that can be set or reset at runtime, and also chosen as an optional argument:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\hms}{ o m }
 {
  \ensuremath
   {
    \IfNoValueTF { #1 }
     {
      \andrec_hms:Ve \l_andrec_hms_sep_str { \tl_to_str:n { #2 } }
     }
     {
      \andrec_hms:ee { \tl_to_str:n { #1 } } { \tl_to_str:n { #2 } }
     }
   }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\sethmssep}{m}
 {
  \str_set:Nn \l_andrec_hms_sep_str { #1 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \andrec_hms:nn
 {
  \group_begin:
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__andrec_hms_seq { #1 } { #2 }
  % normalize the sequence to have three (or more!) items
  \int_compare:nT { \seq_count:N \l__andrec_hms_seq = 1 }
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nn \l__andrec_hms_seq { 0 }
   }
  \int_compare:nT { \seq_count:N \l__andrec_hms_seq = 2 }
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nn \l__andrec_hms_seq { 0 }
   }
  % print
  \bool_set_false:N \l__andrec_hms_thinspace_bool
  \__andrec_hms_print:nn { 1 } { h }
  \__andrec_hms_print:nn { 2 } { m }
  \__andrec_hms_print:nn { 3 } { s }
  \group_end:
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \andrec_hms:nn { Ve,ee }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__andrec_hms_print:nn
 {
  \int_compare:nF { 0\seq_item:Nn \l__andrec_hms_seq { #1 } = 0 }
   {
    \bool_if:NT \l__andrec_hms_thinspace_bool { \, }
    \int_eval:n { 0\seq_item:Nn \l__andrec_hms_seq { #1 } } \, \mathrm{#2}
    \bool_set_true:N \l__andrec_hms_thinspace_bool
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\sethmssep{:}

\begin{document}

$\hms{7:40:21}+\hms[;]{3;17;5}+\hms{2:4:20}$

\sethmssep{;}

$\hms{12;41;}+\hms{0;47;20}+\hms{7;0;37}$

\sethmssep{,}

$\hms{5,12,45}-\hms[;]{4;9}$

\end{document}
```

The output is the same. Using “stringifications”, we overcome the problems with babel.

So long as you don't want negative numbers, here's a modification that allows decimal numbers in the input. Note that you have to input the figures with a decimal point nontheless, but the output can be made to respect the locale.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{locale=FR}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\hms}{ o m }
 {
  \ensuremath
   {
    \IfNoValueTF { #1 }
     {
      \andrec_hms:Ve \l_andrec_hms_sep_str { \tl_to_str:n { #2 } }
     }
     {
      \andrec_hms:ee { \tl_to_str:n { #1 } } { \tl_to_str:n { #2 } }
     }
   }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\sethmssep}{m}
 {
  \str_set:Nn \l_andrec_hms_sep_str { #1 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \andrec_hms:nn
 {
  \group_begin:
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__andrec_hms_seq { #1 } { #2 }
  % normalize the sequence to have three (or more!) items
  \int_compare:nT { \seq_count:N \l__andrec_hms_seq = 1 }
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nn \l__andrec_hms_seq { 0 }
   }
  \int_compare:nT { \seq_count:N \l__andrec_hms_seq = 2 }
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nn \l__andrec_hms_seq { 0 }
   }
  % print
  \bool_set_false:N \l__andrec_hms_thinspace_bool
  \__andrec_hms_print:nn { 1 } { h }
  \__andrec_hms_print:nn { 2 } { m }
  \__andrec_hms_print:nn { 3 } { s }
  \group_end:
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \andrec_hms:nn { Ve,ee }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__andrec_hms_print:nn
 {
  \fp_compare:nF { 0\seq_item:Nn \l__andrec_hms_seq { #1 } = 0 }
   {
    \bool_if:NT \l__andrec_hms_thinspace_bool { \, }
    \num{\fp_eval:n { 0\seq_item:Nn \l__andrec_hms_seq { #1 } }} \, \mathrm{#2}
    \bool_set_true:N \l__andrec_hms_thinspace_bool
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\sethmssep{:}

\begin{document}

$\hms{1.5::}=\num{1.5}\times\hms{:60:}=\hms{:90:}$ % new

$\hms{7:40:21}+\hms[;]{3;17;5}+\hms{2:4:20}$

\sethmssep{;}

$\hms{12;41;}+\hms{0;47;20}+\hms{7;0;37}$

\sethmssep{,}

$\hms{5,12,45}-\hms[;]{4;9}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your interest in this question. Is it possible to make the separator an option (local or global) so that I can define `:` or `;` or any other symbol as separator?

Comment: @AndréC You're looking for trouble, as you know that `:` is a nuisance when `babel-french` is used.

Comment: Yes, that's right, I forgot that. To write a question here, I wrongly Americanize my code.

Comment: @AndréC Well, a bit more complicated, but it could be done. See edit.

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly

Comment: Can you make sure that the minutes are displayed with `min` as it is used today and not with `m` as it was used in 1957?

Comment: Is it possible to make the hours and minutes as decimal so that you can easily write `$\hms{1.5::}=1.5\times\hms{:60:}=\hms{:90:}$`?

Comment: @AndréC Your wish is my command. `;-)`

Comment: Thank you for this wonderful macro. Is it possible to also do with fractions in order to write easily   `$\hms{:15}=\hms{15/60}=\hms{1/4}=\hms{0.25}$` ?
And can you write `min` for minutes instead of `m` ?

Comment: @AndréC I'm not developing this further, sorry. For `min` there is an obvious place to change.

Comment: Yes, I know that the change is obvious for the minutes. For fractions, it's a pity, it would have made it easier to write minute to hour conversions (while decimals make it easier to write hour to minute conversions). But you're the leader. Thanks again for this macro.

Answer (score 12):

Just slightly modifying your code:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{ifmtarg}
    \usepackage{siunitx}
    \sisetup{number-unit-separator=\,}
    \makeatletter
    \newcommand{\sitime}[1]{\sitime@aux#1;;;\@nil}
    \def\sitime@aux#1;#2;#3;#4\@nil{%
      \@ifmtarg{#1#2#3}%
      {%
        \PackageError{siunitx (modified)}%
                     {Empty \string\sitime\space argument}{}%
      }%
    {%
    \@ifmtarg{#1}{}{\SI{#1}{\hour}\@ifmtarg{#2#3}{}{\csname l_siunitx_number_unit_separator_tl\endcsname}}%
    \@ifmtarg{#2}{}{~ \SI{#2}{\minute}\@ifmtarg{#3}{}{\csname l_siunitx_number_unit_separator_tl\endcsname}}%
    \@ifmtarg{#3}{}{~\SI{#3}{\second}}%
    }%
    }
    \makeatother
    \newcommand{\sep}{\qquad}
    \begin{document}

    $\sitime{10;7;12}-\sitime{9;13;8}$

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Modified code to use `:` as a separator for the arguments: use

```
    \makeatletter
    \newcommand{\sitime}[1]{\sitime@aux#1:::\@nil}
    \def\sitime@aux#1:#2:#3:#4\@nil{%
      \@ifmtarg{#1#2#3}%
      {%
        \PackageError{siunitx (modified)}%
                     {Empty \string\sitime\space argument}{}%
      }%
    {%
    \@ifmtarg{#1}{}{\SI{#1}{\hour}\@ifmtarg{#2#3}{}{\csname l_siunitx_number_unit_separator_tl\endcsname}}%
    \@ifmtarg{#2}{}{\ \SI{#2}{\minute}\@ifmtarg{#3}{}{\csname l_siunitx_number_unit_separator_tl\endcsname}}%
    \@ifmtarg{#3}{}{\ \SI{#3}{\second}}%
    }%
    }
    \makeatother
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in this question. Is it possible to make the separator an option (local or global) so that I can define `:` or `;` or any other symbol as separator?

Comment: Do you mean the separator between number and unit components of the duration?

Comment: I think of the separator of the macro so that I can choose between `\sitime{10:7:12}` `\sitime{10;7;12}` or even `\sitime{10,7,12}` etc.

Comment: It's a minor modification. Please see  my addendum for that. B.t.w., does the Lebossé-Hémery series still exist?

Comment: They only exist in second-hand. Some of them can be found here: https://manuelsanciens.blogspot.com/p/maths-college-lycee-prepa.html

Comment: As egreg points out in his answer, so, with this separator, it is `\usepackage[French]{babel}` that complains because of the sign `:`

Comment: Yes, it's an active character. However, `;`   is also an  active character.

Comment: Yes, but with the semicolon, there is no compilation error with babel (I don't know why, by the way).

Comment: I'll try to find a solution, but anyway, if you compile with lualatex or xelatex, there should be no problem.