How do you modify a macro to distinguish between no argument and an argument equal to zero?
The macro defined below by @egreg here is used to write durations in hours, minutes and seconds.
It has been modified here by @HoodChatham.
This macro, which works very well, makes a mistake because it does not write 0 h. When the number of hours is zero, it displays nothing at all.
It doesn't distinguish between the case where the argument is 0 (zero) and the case where it's empty, which means it's absent.
How can we modify it so that it displays 0h when \hms{0} is written, instead of nothing at all as at present?
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{siunitx}
 \sisetup{locale=FR}
%--------------------------------
\ExplSyntaxOn
% Is it possible to adapt a duration calculation macro to use it in a foreach loop?
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/516963/138900
\NewDocumentCommand{\hms}{ o m }
 {
  \ensuremath
   {
    \IfNoValueTF { #1 }
     {
      \andrec_hms:Ve \l_andrec_hms_sep_str { #2 } % Used to say \tl_to_str:n { #2 }
     }
     {
      \andrec_hms:ee { \tl_to_str:n { #1 } } { #2 } % Used to say \tl_to_str:n { #2 }
     }
   }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\sethmssep}{m}
 {
  \str_set:Nn \l_andrec_hms_sep_str { #1 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \andrec_hms:nn
 {
  \group_begin:
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__andrec_hms_seq { #1 } { #2 }
  % normalize the sequence to have three (or more!) items
  \int_compare:nT { \seq_count:N \l__andrec_hms_seq = 1 }
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nn \l__andrec_hms_seq { 0 }
   }
  \int_compare:nT { \seq_count:N \l__andrec_hms_seq = 2 }
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nn \l__andrec_hms_seq { 0 }
   }
  % print
  \bool_set_false:N \l__andrec_hms_thinspace_bool
  \__andrec_hms_print:nn { 1 } { h }
  \__andrec_hms_print:nn { 2 } { min }
  \__andrec_hms_print:nn { 3 } { s }
  \group_end:
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \andrec_hms:nn { Ve,ee }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__andrec_hms_print:nn
 {
  \fp_compare:nF { 0\seq_item:Nn \l__andrec_hms_seq { #1 } = 0 }
   {
    \bool_if:NT \l__andrec_hms_thinspace_bool { \, }
    \num{\fp_eval:n { 0\seq_item:Nn \l__andrec_hms_seq { #1 } }} \, \mathrm{#2}
    \bool_set_true:N \l__andrec_hms_thinspace_bool
   }
 }
 
 \ExplSyntaxOff

 \sethmssep{:}   


 \begin{document}

Lorsqu'il est \hms{0:} au méridien origine de Greenwich, l'heure en un lieu donné, comptée de 0 à \hms{24}, est le quotient par 15 de sa longitude comptée de \ang{0} à \ang{360} vers l'Est.

Lorsqu'il est 0\,h au méridien origine de Greenwich, l'heure en un lieu donné, comptée de 0 à \hms{24}, est le quotient par 15 de sa longitude comptée de \ang{0} à \ang{360} vers l'Est.
\end{document}



At a glance, it seems like \fp_compare:nF { 0\seq_item:Nn \l__andrec_hms_seq { #1 } = 0 } should have a true branch.

You can make \__andrec_hms_print:nn set a boolean to be true if the \fp_compare is false (so if the input is not zero), then in \andrec_hms:nn after all the \__andrec_hms_print:nn, check if the boolean is false. This works with input 0, 0:, 0:0:0, etc.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{locale=FR}
%--------------------------------
\ExplSyntaxOn
% Is it possible to adapt a duration calculation macro to use it in a foreach loop?
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/516963/138900
\bool_new:N \l__andrec_hms_notzero_bool
\bool_new:N \l__andrec_hms_thinspace_bool
\seq_new:N \l__andrec_hms_seq
\str_new:N \l_andrec_hms_sep_str

\NewDocumentCommand{\hms}{ o m }
 {
  \ensuremath
   {
    \IfNoValueTF { #1 }
     {
      \andrec_hms:Ve \l_andrec_hms_sep_str { #2 } % Used to say \tl_to_str:n { #2 }
     }
     {
      \andrec_hms:ee { \tl_to_str:n { #1 } } { #2 } % Used to say \tl_to_str:n { #2 }
     }
   }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\sethmssep}{m}
 {
  \str_set:Nn \l_andrec_hms_sep_str { #1 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \andrec_hms:nn
 {
  \group_begin:
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__andrec_hms_seq { #1 } { #2 }
  % normalize the sequence to have three (or more!) items
  \int_compare:nT { \seq_count:N \l__andrec_hms_seq = 1 }
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nn \l__andrec_hms_seq { 0 }
   }
  \int_compare:nT { \seq_count:N \l__andrec_hms_seq = 2 }
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nn \l__andrec_hms_seq { 0 }
   }
  % print
  \bool_set_false:N \l__andrec_hms_thinspace_bool
  \bool_set_false:N \l__andrec_hms_notzero_bool
  \__andrec_hms_print:nn { 1 } { h }
  \__andrec_hms_print:nn { 2 } { min }
  \__andrec_hms_print:nn { 3 } { s }
  \bool_if:NF \l__andrec_hms_notzero_bool { 0 \, \mathrm{h}}
  \group_end:
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \andrec_hms:nn { Ve,ee }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__andrec_hms_print:nn
 {
  \fp_compare:nF { 0\seq_item:Nn \l__andrec_hms_seq { #1 } = 0 }
   {
    \bool_if:NT \l__andrec_hms_thinspace_bool { \, }
    \num{\fp_eval:n { 0\seq_item:Nn \l__andrec_hms_seq { #1 } }} \, \mathrm{#2}
    \bool_set_true:N \l__andrec_hms_thinspace_bool
    \bool_set_true:N \l__andrec_hms_notzero_bool
   }
 }
 
\ExplSyntaxOff

\sethmssep{:}   


\begin{document}

Lorsqu'il est \hms{0:} au méridien origine de Greenwich, l'heure en un lieu donné, comptée de 0 à \hms{24}, est le quotient par 15 de sa longitude comptée de \ang{0} à \ang{360} vers l'Est.

Lorsqu'il est 0\,h au méridien origine de Greenwich, l'heure en un lieu donné, comptée de 0 à \hms{24}, est le quotient par 15 de sa longitude comptée de \ang{0} à \ang{360} vers l'Est.
\end{document}


