How do you modify a macro that writes durations in hours, minutes and seconds to include days?
The macro defined below by @egreg here is used to write durations in hours, minutes and seconds.
It has been modified here by @HoodChatham.
How can I modify it without changing its behavior, so that it also takes days into account?
That is, \hms{1:7:35:43} displays 1 j 7 h 35 min 43 s
and \hms{2} displays 2 j and \hms{::12} displays 12 min?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}
% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/511874/138900
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{locale=FR}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\hms}{ o m }
 {
  \ensuremath
   {
    \IfNoValueTF { #1 }
     {
      \andrec_hms:Ve \l_andrec_hms_sep_str { #2 } % Used to say \tl_to_str:n { #2 }
     }
     {
      \andrec_hms:ee { \tl_to_str:n { #1 } } { #2 } % Used to say \tl_to_str:n { #2 }
     }
   }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\sethmssep}{m}
 {
  \str_set:Nn \l_andrec_hms_sep_str { #1 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \andrec_hms:nn
 {
  \group_begin:
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__andrec_hms_seq { #1 } { #2 }
  % normalize the sequence to have three (or more!) items
  \int_compare:nT { \seq_count:N \l__andrec_hms_seq = 1 }
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nn \l__andrec_hms_seq { 0 }
   }
  \int_compare:nT { \seq_count:N \l__andrec_hms_seq = 2 }
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nn \l__andrec_hms_seq { 0 }
   }
  % print
  \bool_set_false:N \l__andrec_hms_thinspace_bool
  \__andrec_hms_print:nn { 1 } { h }
  \__andrec_hms_print:nn { 2 } { min }
  \__andrec_hms_print:nn { 3 } { s }
  \group_end:
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \andrec_hms:nn { Ve,ee }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__andrec_hms_print:nn
 {
  \fp_compare:nF { 0\seq_item:Nn \l__andrec_hms_seq { #1 } = 0 }
   {
    \bool_if:NT \l__andrec_hms_thinspace_bool { \, }
    \num{\fp_eval:n { 0\seq_item:Nn \l__andrec_hms_seq { #1 } }} \, \mathrm{#2}
    \bool_set_true:N \l__andrec_hms_thinspace_bool
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\sethmssep{:}
\begin{document}
$\hms{1.5::}=\num{1.5}\times\hms{:60:}=\hms{:90:}$ % new

$\hms{7:40:21}+\hms[;]{3;17;5}+\hms{2:4:20}$

\sethmssep{;}

$\hms{12;41;}+\hms{0;47;20}+\hms{7;0;37}$

\sethmssep{,}

$\hms{5,12,45}-\hms[;]{4;9}$
\end{document} 



The change is straightforward.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{locale=FR}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\jhms}{ o m }
 {
  \ensuremath
   {
    \IfNoValueTF { #1 }
     {
      \andrec_jhms:Ve \l_andrec_jhms_sep_str { #2 } % Used to say \tl_to_str:n { #2 }
     }
     {
      \andrec_jhms:ee { \tl_to_str:n { #1 } } { #2 } % Used to say \tl_to_str:n { #2 }
     }
   }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\setjhmssep}{m}
 {
  \str_set:Nn \l_andrec_jhms_sep_str { #1 }
 }

\str_new:N \l_andrec_jhms_sep_str
\seq_new:N \l__andrec_jhms_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \andrec_jhms:nn
 {
  \group_begin:
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__andrec_jhms_seq { #1 } { #2 }
  % normalize the sequence to have four items
  \prg_replicate:nn { 4 - \seq_count:N \l__andrec_jhms_seq }
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nn \l__andrec_jhms_seq { 0 }
   }
  % print
  \bool_set_false:N \l__andrec_jhms_thinspace_bool
  \__andrec_jhms_print:nn { 1 } { j }
  \__andrec_jhms_print:nn { 2 } { h }
  \__andrec_jhms_print:nn { 3 } { min }
  \__andrec_jhms_print:nn { 4 } { s }
  \group_end:
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \andrec_jhms:nn { Ve,ee }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__andrec_jhms_print:nn
 {
  \fp_compare:nF { 0\seq_item:Nn \l__andrec_jhms_seq { #1 } = 0 }
   {
    \bool_if:NT \l__andrec_jhms_thinspace_bool { \, }
    \num{\fp_eval:n { 0\seq_item:Nn \l__andrec_jhms_seq { #1 } }} \, \mathrm{#2}
    \bool_set_true:N \l__andrec_jhms_thinspace_bool
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\setjhmssep{:}

\begin{document}

``\jhms{1:7:35:43}'' should be ``1\,j\,7\,h 35\,min\,43\,s''

``\jhms{2}'' should be ``2\,j``

``\jhms{::12}'' should be ``12\,min''

``\jhms{:::10}'' should be ``10\,s''

\end{document} 



I'm bad, I hadn't noticed that you'd changed the name of the macro. Thank you very much, it works!

@AndréC I tried \draw (\h,.15)--++(0,-.3) node{$\jhms{:\h:\min}$}; in the \foreach loop and it works.
